# Does php trim() remove line breaks?

Tags: php

I am creating an application that takes a "swipe" from a magnetic reader.  The string that is returned from the magnetic reader has a line break after the text.  Can I use php trim() to remove the linebreak (and obviously any pre or post whitespace)?

Comment: In these sort of situations, why not just try it and see?

Comment: Line breaks are a type of whitespace.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Yes it does, see [the manual](http://php.net/trim):

> This function returns a string with whitespace stripped from the beginning and end of `str`. Without the second parameter, `trim()` will strip these characters:
>
> `" "` (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
> `"\t"` (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
> `"\n"` (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
> `"\r"` (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
> `"\0"` (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
> `"\x0B"` (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.

Answer (score 15):

Also note: `trim($string, "\n")` or `trim($string, " ")`

Answer (score 2):

Note that trim will not remove it by default, if it has `breakline: <br>` at the end, so be careful with that.

Otherwise @Pekka's @Petah's answer is good.